# Как правильно преобразовать целочисленный массив в ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Изучаю книгу Берта Бейтса и Кати Сьерры по Java.

> При реализации игры (по принципу морского боя) с использованием класса ArrayList из стандартной
>   библиотеки Java(API) возникает ошибка:
>
> **The method setLocationCells(ArrayList) in the type
>   SimpleDotCom is not applicable for the arguments (int[])**

Сама игра выглядит так:

```
          public class SimpleDotComTestDrive {

                public static void main(String[] args) {

                    //переменная для хранения количества ходов
                    int numOfGuesses = 0;
                    //специальный класс, который содержит метод для приема пользовательского ввода.
                    GameHelper helper = new GameHelper();

                    SimpleDotCom theDotCom = new SimpleDotCom();
                    //генерируем случайное число для первой ячейки и используем его для формирования массива ячеек.
                    int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

                    // Создаем массив для местоположения (три последовательности числа из семи)
                     int[] locations = {randomNum, randomNum+1, randomNum+2};

                    //передаем местоположение ячеек(массив).

                    theDotCom.setLocationCells(locations);//В этой строчке ошибка с вызовом сеттера setLocationCells

                    //создаем булевую переменную, чтобы проверять в цикле, не закончилась ли игра
                    boolean isAlive = true;

                    while(isAlive == true) {    
                        //получаем строку вводимую пользователем
                        String guess = helper.getUserInput("Введите число");

                        //проверить полученные данные: сохраняем возвращенный результат в переменную типа String
                        String result = theDotCom.checkYourself(guess);

                        //Инкрементируем количество попыток
                        numOfGuesses++;



                        //Если да, то присваиваем isAlive значение false (так как не хотим продолжать цикл) и выводим на экран количество попыток
                        if (result.equals("Потопил")) {
                            isAlive = false;
                            System.out.println("Вам потребовалось " + numOfGuesses + " попыток(и)");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            public class SimpleDotCom {

                private ArrayList<Integer> locationCells;

                public void setLocationCells(ArrayList<Integer> loc) { //сеттер
                    locationCells = loc;
                }

                public String checkYourself(String stringGuess) {

                    // Создаем переменную для хранения результата, который будем возвращять.
                    // Присваиваем по умолчанию строковое значение "Мимо"(то есть подразумеваем
                    // промах).
                    String result = "Мимо";

                    //Проверяем содержится ли загаданная пользователем ячейка внутри ArrayList, запрашивая ее индекс.
                    //Если ее нет в списке, то indexOf() возвращает -1.
                    int index = locationCells.indexOf(stringGuess);

                    //Если индекс больше или равен нулю, то загаданная пользователем ячейка определенно
                    //находится в списке, поэтому удаляем ее.
                    if (index >= 0) {
                        locationCells.remove(index);

                        //Если список пустой, значит, это было попадание
                        if(locationCells.isEmpty()) {
                            result = "Потопил";
                        } else {
                            result = "Попал";
                        }
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            }


public class GameHelper {

    public String getUserInput(String prompt) {
        String inputLine = null;
        System.out.print(prompt + " ");
        try {
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            inputLine = is.readLine();
            if (inputLine.length() == 0)
                return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException:" + e);
        }
        return inputLine;
    }
}
```

Comment: Всем добрый день! Вот еще в продолжение по этому вопросу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1534661/562979

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените Вашу строчку таким образом

```
theDotCom.setLocationCells(Arrays.asList(locations));
```

Только помните, что создание коллекции указанным способом намертво привязывает ее к самому массиву. Когда вы попытаетесь менять ее размер, то получите проблему. 
В остальных случаях метод вполне годится для использования.
Это кажется не очень логичным на первый взгляд, ведь, если мы получаем коллекцию, то вполне логично , что мы не хотим зависеть от ее размера. Но на самом деле это позволяет избежать глупых преобразований. Ведь если вы создаете массив, то уверены в его размере. Если так, то вас не должна смущать коллекция, привязанная к размеру массива. Если вы не знаете количество элементов, то вам необходимо сразу создавать коллекцию и добавлять элементы уже в нее, а не создавать никому не нужный массив с целью его дальнейшего преобразования.

Answer (score 1):

```
  List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(locations);
```

Comment: Если нужен полноценный java.util.ArrayList, то List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(locations));